# Is it possible to use a Crystal Report designed for one database on another without modifying the DB or fields?

Tags: crystal-reports, sap-business-one-di-api

i want to import one crystal report to another database like i have created a report for a database and i want to use it for another database(another client) is there any possiblity to do this without any changes in DB and fields. if does then please tell why?

i did not try but i have checked on somewhere this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the menu option of ***Database, Set Datesource Location...***